# Can "have" in perfect tenses be used to make questions?

Tags: questions, perfect-constructions, do-support

> A: I have a bus.
>   B:Have you a bus?

Here *have* is used to make a question by bring *have* in the beginning of a sentence. My question is can we behave the same toward *have* in perfect tenses? For example, in emphasizing sentences we bring modal first, as in:

> Little have I knowledge of that subject.

*have* came almost first. Can I do the same on a sentence making the following sentence?

> Also less often have managers used praise and acclamation as a motivating factor.

Comment: Your second sentence is okay.  Your first one isn't.  You *could* say any of: Little do I know on that subject.  Or Little knowledge do I have on that subject. Or  Little knowledge have I of that subject.  Or Knowledge of that subject have I little.

Comment: "Have you a bus?",or "little knowledge do I have on that subject" is grammatically OK but highly non-idiomatic, at least in the US. Prefer "Do you have a bus?" or "I know little about that subject". Also it would be much more common to say "I don't know much..." than "I know little...".

Comment: 1) *Have* is not a modal. 2) In  your first three sentences it is a *lexical* verb: an ordinary verb equivalent to *possess*. *Have* in this sense is only rarely fronted today; that use has been steadily declining for 150 years. 3) "Little have I knowledge" is not idiomatic; "Little knowledge do I have" is aceptable but very literary. 4) *Have* in your last sentence is an auxiliary. *Less often have managers used* is acceptable, but the *also* in front of it is unusual; it would ordinarily occur only if parallelling the same structure in the previous sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> Have you a bus?

While that may be gramatically correct, using that in normal conversation would probably earn you some weird looks. Try using

> Do you have a bus?

instead.

> Little have I knowledge of that subject.

I'm not sure myself of the grammatical correctness here, but again that sounds awkward (and a bit like Yoda from the film *Star Wars*!).

> I have little knowledge of that subject

would be better.

> Also less often have managers used praise and acclamation as a motivating factor.

This sentence doesn't really make sense. You might be trying to say either:

> [also] Managers used praise and acclamation for motivation less often.
>
> As a motivating factor, managers used praise and acclamation less.

Comment: Oh Gosh! I don't want to look like Yoda!

Comment: @MehdiHaghgoo It's OK. You won't *look* like Yoda. Only *sound* like Yoda, you will.